# UILabel combine font size

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I use a UITextField to input text and automatically the UILabel shows that text.

Now, I want to increase the second character's font size, ONLY if user typed 3 characters, if user typed less or more than 3, then all characters should get the default font size.

See attached image.

I want to use NSAttributedText, but I don't know how to increase the second character size only.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[myTextField attributedText] mutableCopy];
NSDictionary *sizeAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0]};
NSRange secondChar = NSMakeRange(1,1);
[text setAttributes:sizeAttributes range:secondChar];
[myTextField setAttributedText:text];
// might want to release text here, to avoid memory leak
```

Comment: yes, that change the 2nd character in _textField, but I want to change that in UILabel. I tried to replace myTextField from your code with _label, but no changes

Comment: your original question doesn't describe a separate textField and label at all, or say which one you want to do what. But anyway you can use the same code for a UILabel just fine. Post your attempt in an edit and describe what didn't work...?